# How to Change Size of Pivot Item Header in Template

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm looking to be able to modify the default Pivot template to change the size of the Pivot Item headers. How might I do this with the following Style

```
<Style x:Key="PivotStyle" TargetType="phone:Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:Pivot">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid CacheMode="BitmapCache" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
                            <Grid.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1.0" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Grid.Background>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Grid.Row="2" />
                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Margin="24,17,0,-7" />
                        <Primitives:PivotHeadersControl x:Name="HeadersListElement" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" FontSize="28" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I am trying to get this to mimick the following

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by changing headers size? `<PivotHeadersControl ... FontSize="28"../>`?

Comment: Updating the font size on <Primitives:PivotHeadersControl x:Name="HeadersListElement" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" FontSize="18" Grid.Row="1"/> had no effect. Changed to FontSize="18" to test.

Answer (score 11):

You can surely change your Pivot Header's font-size, family and so on by changing HeaderTemplate:

```
<phone:Pivot Title="PivotTest" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle}">
     <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="10"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
     <phone:PivotItem Header="One">
          // item 1  
     </phone:PivotItem>
     <phone:PivotItem Header="Two">
          // item 2
     </phone:PivotItem>
</phone:Pivot>
```

**EDIT** - within a style:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myHeader">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="10"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="PivotStyle" TargetType="phone:Pivot">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource myHeader}"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        ....
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go. My ultimate goal however was to create a style so I can apply it to all pivot items uniformly in my app and then change the style when necessary.

Comment: @Matthew That is not a problem (see edit) - you can define your DataTemplate and set it with a setter in Pivot's Style.